# Select Query array and array from POST not lining up

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, mysqli

when the user inputs the form, I have know way of knowing what the user can input because there are hundreds of options in the database.
I am using a foreach loop to get the categories and the cost from the posted field that they chose example:

```
<td><?php foreach($pcategories as $value){echo "$value <br>";}?></td>

$qty    $pcategories    $cost    $Rate   
1       Bicycles        100      45
7       Auto Parts      200      60
5       Alarm Sys       300      35
```

The rate is then being selected from the query below

```
<?php $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customs") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
      $sql = "SELECT `categories`, `rate`, `elevy`  FROM `lt_products` WHERE `categories` IN ('".implode("','",$pcategories)."')";
               $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)or die(mysql_error());
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
                       <?php echo $row["rate"]; ?> <br>
        <?php } ?>
```

Here's the problem the query is pulling the correct rates base on the categories the user in putted
but the rates are not coming out to match the order of the categories the user input.

Above rates should actually look like this below but instead that is what im getting above

```
$qty    $pcategories    $cost    $Rate   
1       Bicycles        100      35
7       Auto Parts      200      60
5       Alarm Sys       300      45
```

The select query seems to be coming out in alphabetical order based on the pcategories field in the table.

I dont know whats the best way to fix this so that the actual rate matches the categories the user chose.

Any help would be great thank you

Comment: If you want the results in a specific order, you need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting multiple columns of output when you just echo the rate.

Comment: Echo all the columns together, and the rate should match the category correctly.

Comment: the rate is coming from a table that includes the categories and the rate, the $qty the $pcategories and the cost are coming from the users input from the form.

Comment: You need to use `ORDER BY` in the query so that the results are produced in the same order that you used when you created the form.

Comment: i use this $sql = "SELECT `categories`, `rate`, `elevy`  FROM `lt_products` WHERE `categories` IN ('".implode("','",$pcategories)."')"; to get the match between the post variable and the query. they get the right categories based on the users post but like i said just not in the right order

Comment: That's the same as the question says.

Comment: How many times do I have to say it? If you don't use ORDER BY, the results can come in any order. The order of the items in the `IN()` list is irrelevant.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction on how to use the order by with the implode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function to order the results based on their position in `$pcategories`

```
$sql = "SELECT `categories`, `rate`, `elevy`  
        FROM `lt_products` 
        WHERE `categories` IN ('".implode("','",$pcategories)."') 
        ORDER BY FIELD(categories, '".implode("','",$pcategories)."')";
```